# Google Analytics API: How to pull accounts, getting listManagementAccounts() on non-object error

Tags: php, api, google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api

**EDIT** - this tutorial (although almost like the tutorial by google) was what finally made things work: http://teev.io/blog/google-analytics-api-php

I'm trying to follow the tutorial that's mentioned here:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/service-php

I've followed all of the steps:

1. Created a project.
2. Created a Service account.
   (when prompted for JSON or P12, I chose JSON)
3. I ran `composer require google/apiclient:^2.0` in putty and updated my composer.json file.
4. Placed my `service-account-credentials.json` file that I just downloaded into folder `/public_html`
5. Created file `HelloAnalytics.php` and placed it into `/public_html` folder.

HelloAnalytics.php :

```
<?php

// Load the Google API PHP Client Library.
require_once '/home/user/vendor/autoload.php';

$analytics = initializeAnalytics();
$profile = getFirstProfileId($analytics);
$results = getResults($analytics, $profile);
printResults($results);

function initializeAnalytics()
{
    // Creates and returns the Analytics Reporting service object.

    // Use the developers console and download your service account
    // credentials in JSON format. Place them in this directory or
    // change the key file location if necessary.
    $KEY_FILE_LOCATION = __DIR__ . '/service-account-credentials.json';

    // Create and configure a new client object.
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName("Hello Analytics Reporting");
    $client->setAuthConfig($KEY_FILE_LOCATION);
    $client->setScopes(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly']);
    $analytics = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting($client);

    return $analytics;
}

function getFirstProfileId($analytics) {
    // Get the user's first view (profile) ID.

    // Get the list of accounts for the authorized user.
    $accounts = $analytics->management_accounts->listManagementAccounts();

    if (count($accounts->getItems()) > 0) {
        $items = $accounts->getItems();
        $firstAccountId = $items[0]->getId();

        // Get the list of properties for the authorized user.
        $properties = $analytics->management_webproperties
            ->listManagementWebproperties($firstAccountId);

        if (count($properties->getItems()) > 0) {
            $items = $properties->getItems();
            $firstPropertyId = $items[0]->getId();

            // Get the list of views (profiles) for the authorized user.
            $profiles = $analytics->management_profiles
                ->listManagementProfiles($firstAccountId, $firstPropertyId);

            if (count($profiles->getItems()) > 0) {
                $items = $profiles->getItems();

                // Return the first view (profile) ID.
                return $items[0]->getId();

            } else {
                throw new Exception('No views (profiles) found for this user.');
            }
        } else {
            throw new Exception('No properties found for this user.');
        }
    } else {
        throw new Exception('No accounts found for this user.');
    }
}

function getResults($analytics, $profileId) {
    // Calls the Core Reporting API and queries for the number of sessions
    // for the last seven days.
    return $analytics->data_ga->get(
        'ga:' . $profileId,
        '7daysAgo',
        'today',
        'ga:sessions');
}

function printResults($results) {
    // Parses the response from the Core Reporting API and prints
    // the profile name and total sessions.
    if (count($results->getRows()) > 0) {

        // Get the profile name.
        $profileName = $results->getProfileInfo()->getProfileName();

        // Get the entry for the first entry in the first row.
        $rows = $results->getRows();
        $sessions = $rows[0][0];

        // Print the results.
        print "First view (profile) found: $profileName\n";
        print "Total sessions: $sessions\n";
    } else {
        print "No results found.\n";
    }
}
```

Which sadly produces this error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function listManagementAccounts() on a non-object in....

Any advice on how to actually get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is using the old `v1-master` branch code, but you are trying to use `composer require google/apiclient:^2.0`.

Update your code to match that given in the [link you provided](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/service-php):

```
<?php

// Load the Google API PHP Client Library.
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$analytics = initializeAnalytics();
$profile = getFirstProfileId($analytics);
$results = getResults($analytics, $profile);
printResults($results);
...
```

Comment: I did exactly this. But now I'm getting an error **Call to a member function listManagementAccounts() on a non-object in**, I will revise my question.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of:

```
$analytics = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting($client);
```

Do this:

```
$analytics = new Google_Service_Analytics($client);
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that it's been too late for you. I have had the exactly same issue as you.

By checking session value, I realized that I was not authorized.
So I looked into the document again, and I finally realized that I should set the new service email address to my Google Analytics admin list for "Read & Analyse" by doing like this:

1. click "Admin" on the left bottom corner,
2. click "Account Access Management"
3. click "+"
4. paste your service email address like xxx@yyy.iam.gserviceaccount.com to the address field and add this user to user list.

and you refresh your HelloAnalytics.php.

Good luck!